# How to align results left and right at the same time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyodbc

Using PyQt4, pyodbc and python 3.5.1 i want to align result rows left and right at the same time. i mean:

```
printing resultrow = "column1:column2"
```

but i want to print it like

```
printing resultrow = "column1      :      column2"
```

i'm writing result data to Qt4 App Plain Text Edit Field. Because of results are changing i don't know how many spaces i need to add so i need to align them on Plain Text Edit Field but it's only for one way, at least as far as i know. Please advice me to fix this issue.

Thank you...

Comment: Why not use a widget with columns, like a `QTreeWidget` or a `QTableWidget` to display the data rather than trying to manually align things in a text widget?

Comment: I should try that, thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do alignment and space padding with the normal python string formatting

```
>>> '{:<15}:{:>15}'.format('column1', 'column2')
'column1        :        column2'
```

If you want to make the padding variable

```
width = len(row)
fmt_str = '{{:<{0}}}:{{:>{0}}}'.format(width)
fmt_str.format('column1', 'column2')
```

Comment: This looks perfect, I will write the results

Comment: I'm getting close to it but please teach me how may i replace >15 with something like len(row[0]). I tried {0} with .format but it didn't work

Comment: @fuzunspm Updated the answer